# linebreak in description title

Tags: lists, line-breaking, description

In my document I have a `description` environment. One of the titles in the description is too long to fit in one line and I want to break it. I know this is a bad styling but I can't think of any way to shorten it. I tried `\\` and `\newline` and they didn't work. What else can I do?

I tried to use the mdwlist package. I added the following in the begining of my document:

```
\renewenvironment{description}{
  \begin{basedescript}{%
    \renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{\bfseries##1}%
  }
}{%
  \desclabelstyle{\multilinelabel}

  \end{basedescript}%

}
```

but all I got is the same result.

I also tried this without any effect:

```
\renewenvironment{description}{
  \desclabelstyle{\multilinelabel}
  \begin{basedescript}{%
    \renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{\bfseries##1}%
  }
}{%
  \end{basedescript}%
}
```

I can't use the `\multilinelabel` since the words in the label are too long, thus, I want to use `\pushlabel`. However, this doesn't work even in the example you given (probably, it doesn't know how to break lines). Is there any way to force break lines?

Comment: `\pushlabel` moves the text following the label to the right but does not allow line break at the label. Have a look at the two suggestions at my answer below, that provides line break at the label.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: This is what I did. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your description items may be longer than a line I would suggest to use a paragraph or subparagraph instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand*{\mtol}{This is some more text than fit at ony line but only some
  and not a lot}

\begin{document}
\subparagraph{\mtol} \blindtext
\subparagraph{Or with less text} \blindtext
\subparagraph{\mtol} \blindtext
\subparagraph{\mtol} \blindtext

\end{document}
```

This may result in

[image: result of the example]

This may or may not be what you want. If you don't like the par indent before the label, simply replace `\subparagraph` by `\paragraph`.

Or you may define your own multi line description environment, e.g. using `addmargin` environment of [KOMA-Script package scrextend](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{scrextend}

\newcommand*{\mtol}{This is some more text than fit at ony line but only some
  and not a lot}

\newenvironment{mldescription}{%
  \begin{addmargin}[2em]{1em}
    \setlength{\parindent}{-1em}%
    \newcommand*{\mlitem}[1]{\par\textbf{##1}\quad}\indent
}{%
  \end{addmargin}
  \medskip
}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{mldescription}
\mlitem{\mtol} \blindtext
\mlitem{Or with less text} \blindtext
\mlitem{\mtol} \blindtext
\mlitem{\mtol} \blindtext
\end{mldescription}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

This would result in

[image: result of mldescription list]

That should almost be, what you want. If you want more or less indention or more or less hanging text, simply change the values of the `addmargin` environment or the `\parindent`.

And if you want additional vertical space between the items you may add this to the definition of the new environment too:

```
\newenvironment{mldescription}{%
  \begin{addmargin}[2em]{1em}
    \setlength{\parindent}{-1em}%
    \newcommand*{\mlitem}[1]{\par\medskip% vertical space
      \textbf{##1}\quad}\indent
}{%
  \end{addmargin}
  \bigskip% changed to have more vertical space than between items
}
```

[image: same with vertical space]

If you're already using a KOMA-Script class, you don't need to load package `scrextend`.

Answer (score 24):

The package **enumitem** provide a style just for this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem} % load this one

\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand*{\longtext}{This is some text that runs off the margin
  when used in a description label}

\newenvironment{longdescription}
  {\begin{description}[style=unboxed]}
  {\end{description}}

% Just to get dummy text
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand*{\longtext}{This is some text that runs off the margin
  when used in a description label}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{longdescription}
\item[\longtext] \lipsum*[3]
\item[Normal label] \lipsum*[4]
\end{longdescription}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to surpress the indent for the title? My text starts on the next line first while breaking the line after each item title with `\hfill \\ `. Now I would like to have the second line of the title on the same h-position as the first line.

Comment: @Eric Maybe; but with deep surgery, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 14):

In such situations, where you need multi-line text, you could use `\parbox`, such as

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[\protect{\parbox[t]{1cm}{long\\label}}] text
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image: description list with multi line label]

Here I used the alignment parameter `t` in the optional argument for `\parbox` to get vertical alignment at the top line.

If would like to customize it further, have a look at the [`mdwlist`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdwlist) package, which offers several different styles for description list labels, also for multi-line labels. It also solves the problem with multi-line labels combined with multi-line description.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\begin{document}
\begin{basedescript}{%
  \desclabelstyle{\multilinelabel}
  \desclabelwidth{2cm}}
\item[This is a pretty long text for a label] \blindtext
\item[more] text
\end{basedescript}
\end{document}
```

[image: mdwlist multi-line label example]

Comment: This does not work, if the you have more than one line of text after the `\item` argument (e.g. replace `text` by `\blindtext` using package `blindtext`). To make it work, you need the optional height argument of `\parbox` to fake height/depth. But this may be a problem while page break.

Comment: Sure, with `\parbox` one might have to take more care, as in the case you mentioned, that's why I recommended `mdwlist`. Now I added an example for demonstration.

Comment: Nevertheless the `mdwlist` example is still a problem at page break. Simply add `\blindtext[2]\par\vspace{2\baselineskip}\blindtext[3]` before the `baseddescript` environment to see this. Users should know this.

Comment: Could be fixed with the `needspace` package, if the user insists on using a `description` list. Nevertheless, I answered the specific question how to get a line break in a `description` list, not by recommending something different nor treating cases the OP did not mention. But good that you point to possible problems one would might have to take care of.

Comment: @Schweinebacke I solved that with another `parbox` around the text after `item`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go with @Stefan Kittwitz first approach using \parbox, you can \smash it to avoid line breaks (only!) if your text is longer than the label:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\setlist[description]{leftmargin=!,labelwidth=2.5cm}
\begin{description}
     \item[\protect{\smash{\parbox[t]{2cm}{This is a pretty long text for a label}}}] \blindtext
     \item[\protect{\smash{\parbox[t]{2cm}{This is a pretty long text for a label}}}] Lorem ipsum\\~\\~\\
     \item[\protect{\smash{\parbox[t]{2cm}{This is a pretty long text for a label}}}] \blindtext
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The enumitem package is used for customizing the description label.
Also sorry for making this an answer, my reputation isn't high enough to comment :)