# How do I cause a long label in a description environmnt to wrap?

Tags: lists, labels, enumitem, description

I am using a description environment, and one of my labels is very long

```
\begin{description}
\item[A very long label that I would like to wrap rather than overrunning
the right margin as it currently does. If it helps I am using the enumitem
package, and a solution that depends on it is acceptable.]
\leavevmode
Text following long label.
\end{description}
```

Is there a way to cause the text on the \item to wrap? I'm alrady using enumitem, so a fix that requires it is fine. Thanks.

Comment: Probably [linebreak in description title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35455/134144)  is interesting. In particular `enumitem`'s `style=unboxed` option as in `\begin{description}[style=unboxed]`.

Comment: Thanks. if you put style=unboxed in an answer I'll upcheck it.

Comment: As it is, your question is quite similar to the one I linked in my previous comment. I would therefore suggeest to close yours as a duplicate to the other one. Would you agree?

Comment: There are three answers there; the first and third presented solutions that were clumsier or don't do what I want. The middle answer, by egreg , is what I needed.